# How to fix nesting level exceeded Error with recursive function in SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, sql-server-2014, recursive-query, sql-function

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379805/maximum-stored-procedure-function-trigger-or-view-nesting-level-exceeded-lim) but didn't get any solution there. I have following functions which takes float as input and converts the number into days with some custom logic.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F_GetDurationInDays_BI] 
(
    @TimeInMinutes FLOAT
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
Begin
        If (@TimeInMinutes >= 0 and @TimeInMinutes < 480)
            return (@TimeInMinutes/60)/8                       
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes >= 480 and @TimeInMinutes < 1440)
            return 1
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes >= 1440 and @TimeInMinutes < 1920)
            return 1.5
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes = 1920)
            return 2
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes > 1920)
            return ( select [dbo].[F_GetDurationInDays_BI] (@TimeInMinutes - 1440) +1)

        return 0
End
```

When I am giving some higher values like,

```
select Format(dbo.F_GetDurationInHours_BI (226560), 'N1')
```

I'm getting nesting level exceed exception as below,

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

Is there any way to increase nesting level limit or any other possible way. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure what your logic is, but it seems clear that you can convert this from a recursive function to a `while` loop.

Comment: Instead of subtraction, use division. If you _really_ insist on using subtraction, use a while loop instead of recursion. It will work because it doesn't use recursion, but it will be slow for big numbers.

Comment: While loop could cause performance issue and duplicate code as well. Is there any way to increase nesting level limit?

Comment: @Code_Mode Your recursion is behaving ***exactly*** like a while loop; just with ***extra overhead*** of pushing each iteration as a recursive call onto the stack. Increasing the nesting limit will get it working with _slightly_ bigger numbers but ***slower*** than a while loop. But as I said earlier, you should be using ***division*** - not loops and certainly _NOT_ recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this to an iterative loop rather than a recursive function call.  The logic is something like this:

```
Begin
   declare @counter int;
   select @counter = 0;

   while (true)
   begin
        If (@TimeInMinutes >= 0 and @TimeInMinutes < 480)
            return @counter + (@TimeInMinutes/60)/8  ;                     
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes >= 480 and @TimeInMinutes < 1440)
            return @counter + 1;
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes >= 1440 and @TimeInMinutes < 1920)
            return @counter + 1.5;
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes = 1920)
            return @counter + 2;
        Else If (@TimeInMinutes > 1920)
        begin
            select @TimeInMinutes = (@TimeInMinutes - 1440);
            select @counter := @counter + 1;
        end;
     end;
    return @counter;
End;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Aaargh Gordon, why? I know you know how horrible and wrong this is. It doesn't help OP learn anything.